# iOS app crashes when remote disable is set for force upgrade

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

My iOS app uses [IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundation](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/) client sdk. I am facing a weird issue at a particular point. We want to test the forcefull upgrade scenario. As we mark any published iOS app version outdated we want our customers to update the installed iOS version from the app store.

To do this, we just mark the `MFP application` version (`worklight console`) expired. Once we do this and as soon the iOS app launches we start getting the forceful upgrade message along with the download URL (I verified this alert is triggered from the WLClient library itself and we don't have access to that piece of code). But here the issue is our app is getting crashed after that alert  as if we perform any activity in our app like (crash frequeny is 7-8 out 10 attempts).

We have a screen where we have several mfp adapter calls (as these services are called again we get the same forcefull alert) but after certain attempts app is getting crashed.

**Here are some of the crash stack trace.**

`This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread after the engine was accessed from the main thread. This can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.
Stack:(
    0   Foundation                          0x00000001f03a7474 <redacted> + 96
    1   Foundation                          0x00000001f01bc554 <redacted> + 76
    2   Foundation                          0x00000001f01bc464 <redacted> + 120
    3   Foundation                          0x00000001f01bc228 <redacted> + 112
    4   UIKitCore                           0x000000021c0e31b8 <redacted> + 284
    5   UIKitCore                           0x000000021c0f5e54 <redacted> + 1292
    6   QuartzCore                          0x00000001f3cc61f0 <redacted> + 184
    7   QuartzCore                          0x00000001f3ccb198 <redacted> + 332
    8   QuartzCore                          0x00000001f3c2e0a8 <redacted> + 348
    9   QuartzCore                          0x00000001f3c5c108 <redacted> + 640
    10  QuartzCore                          0x00000001f3c5ccf8 <redacted> + 92
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001ef7c989c <redacted> + 32
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001ef7c45c4 <redacted> + 412
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001ef7c4374 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 468
    14  Foundation                          0x00000001f0191fcc <redacted> + 300
    15  Foundation                          0x00000001f01cd49c <redacted> + 88
    16  APP_Name                         0x0000000104151f4c +[WLAFURLConnectionOperation networkRequestThreadEntryPoint:] + 308
    17  Foundation                          0x00000001f02be6e4 <redacted> + 984
    18  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001ef4582c0 <redacted> + 128
    19  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001ef458220 _pthread_start + 44
    20  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001ef45bcdc thread_start + 4
)
2019-10-10 15:33:04.141027+0400 APP_Name[1012:86063] *** Assertion failure in void RemoveVarFromSortedPriorityVectorList(NSISObjectiveLinearExpression *, NSISLinExpVar)(), /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/Foundation/Foundation-1570.15/Foundation/Layout.subproj/IncrementalSimplex/NSISObjectiveLinearExpression.m:161
2019-10-10 15:33:04.141027+0400 APP_Name[1012:86344] *** Assertion failure in void RemoveVarFromSortedPriorityVectorList(NSISObjectiveLinearExpression *, NSISLinExpVar)(), /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/Foundation/Foundation-1570.15/Foundation/Layout.subproj/IncrementalSimplex/NSISObjectiveLinearExpression.m:161
2019-10-10 15:33:24.575363+0400 APP_Name[1012:86344] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Missing variable 55 in variablesSortedByPriorityVectors'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1ef838518 0x1eea139f8 0x1ef752148 0x1f0261f5c 0x1f03b16c8 0x1f0200934 0x1f01fa030 0x1f03ad7e0 0x1f0271130 0x1f03a68f0 0x1f03a5cb8 0x1f03a6c98 0x1f01bc5f4 0x1f01bc464 0x1f01bc228 0x21c0e31b8 0x21c0f5e54 0x1f3cc61f0 0x1f3ccb198 0x1f3c2e0a8 0x1f3c5c108 0x1f3c5ccf8 0x1ef7c989c 0x1ef7c45c4 0x1ef7c4374 0x1f0191fcc 0x1f01cd49c 0x104151f4c 0x1f02be6e4 0x1ef4582c0 0x1ef458220 0x1ef45bcdc)`

`Uncaught Exception: Engine marked as needing optimization even though it's already in progress.
2019-10-10 16:17:10.853059+0400 ADIB Mobile[1080:95658] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Engine marked as needing optimization even though it's already in progress.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1ef838518 0x1eea139f8 0x1ef752148 0x1f02151c8 0x1f01b5190 0x1f01f7548 0x1f01f6a28 0x1f01f6774 0x1f01f6048 0x21c030330 0x21c030790 0x21c030e88 0x1f03b59ec 0x1f01b2b34 0x1f01b1b58 0x21b3fdf80 0x21b3eba00 0x21c0e85d4 0x21b3eb930 0x21b3eb308 0x21b5f70e0 0x21b5f4c2c 0x21bc78fdc 0x21bc67b2c 0x21bc86540 0x1ef7ca10c 0x1ef7c9a10 0x1ef7c4a74 0x1ef7c4354 0x1f19c479c 0x21bc6db68 0x21d757474 0x104fd1820 0x1ef28a8e0)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException`

When I have put a couple of symbolic breakpoints. I have got to know the alert was displayed from secondary thread (which was triggered from `WLClient` library). Initially it does not crash but after repetitive attempts it gets crashed.

Any idea why it is happening.

[image: look at attached screenshot]

Comment: What is your exact iFix level? Not the MFP version, but your exact fix level - something like 20170721-12345? You should open a case with IBM for deeper investigation.

Comment: I guess you are talking about the complete platformversion. If yes it is `7.1.0.00.20180425-1124` @VivinK  Yes, I will create a support ticket with ibm